# I want to write Relative Xpath for two Web Elements

Tags: xpath

I want to create relative path to the following web elements

Since its a very old application so , its difficult to verify my xpaths on browser console.

1. I want to reach the web element to the text under "Owner" column of the table. 
   [I want to reach the web element to the text under "Owner" column of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbpxB.png)
2. I want to Reach to the second option in the Table "Professional Liability".
   [I want to Reach to the second option in the Table "Professional Liability"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbY84.png)

Comment: This question is incomplete. We need more details.

Comment: Is it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `xpath`

1. xpath for owner.

   ```
   "//td[@sortfield='owner']"
   ```
2. xpath for Professional Liability

```
     "//select[@name='AVAILABLE_COVERAGES']/option[contains(.,'Professional Liability')]"
```